# Intel 7260 HMW in a Dell E6410 - No bluetooth

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, drivers, bluetooth

I have installed a Intel 7260AC in an Intel E6410. The wifi works superbly, but the Bluetooth drivers cannot install. Are there any drivers for it? I have tried the official drivers and other drivers from many forums, but it cannot work.

I currently have two options:

1) Try to get the Bluetooth to work

2) Scrap the Intel 7260AC and try to find a 2x2 or 3x3 card without bluetooth.

I'm stuck on step 1 and cannot find a good card for step 2. Help!

Comment: By official drivers do you mean from the Intel site or Windows Update? See if anything here helps you: [How do I turn on Bluetooth on a Dell Latitude E6410?](http://superuser.com/questions/239077/how-do-i-turn-on-bluetooth-on-a-dell-latitude-e6410?rq=1)

Comment: @Ramhound http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/wireless-products/dual-band-wireless-ac-7260-bluetooth.html

Comment: @Ramhound How?/

Comment: @Ramhound Got it to work. Taped pin 51.

Answer (score 2):

I got the WiFi card to work by taping Pin 51. I don't know why but I think it has to do with the fact that my computer has a hardware switch to disable bluetooth and WiFi.

Comment: Just to clarify what you did.  Did you put tape on 51 or did you provided pressure on/around pin 51?

Comment: @Ramhound Tape. It works perfectly now.

Comment: @Ramhound Also, why was I downvoted.

Comment: Why are you asking me?  Voting is anonymous.